# how to pass servlet generated image to FB.api imgURL function?

Tags: javascript, html, jakarta-ee, facebook-javascript-sdk

my code is here

```
var imgURL="http://localhost:8084/WebApplication6/imagefromservlet";
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
    message:' coffee',
    url:imgURL        
}, function(response){
    alert('getting photo');
    if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured');
    } else {alert('OK');
```

this is showing me ERROR 
    probelm is how cam i pass servlet generated image
    to this "imgURL" so that it can workproperly.
    Servlet "imagefromservlet" generate the edited image for me.Correct this or tell me the correct way to do this ?

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo, but you missed `});` at the end

Comment: its ok now......its because of localhost :) just replaced it with my ip